# HTML Align LEGEND Center

Tags: html

How do I adjust the legend width ? so I can center it on screen.

```
<fieldset>
<legend align="center">LOGIN</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The legend element properties can be modified via CSS just like any other element. Here's an example of a legend with 100% width, centred text and yellow background: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7DnS/1/

### HTML

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>LOGIN</legend>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" name="submit" />
</fieldset>
```

### CSS

```
fieldset { border: 1px solid grey; padding: 10px; }
legend {
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Negative. Works in Firefox, Chrome, IE7-9, Opera.

Comment: With 100% width the <legend> obscures the <fieldset>'s top border.

Comment: how do this without width 100%? :)

Answer (score 4):

```
.simpleSolutionInCss{
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```